# Android marker: onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected

Tags: android, warnings, lint

I have a functional code but after last SDK update  I'm getting this warning:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - onTouch should call View#performClick when a click is detected
>     - implements android.view.View.OnTouchListener.onTouch

```
med.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            detect.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            detect.setEnabled(true);
        }
        //v.performClick();
        Log.e("next", "touch");
        return false;
    }
});

med.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!center) {
            send("1");
        } else {
            send("2");
        }
        Vibrate(100);
        Log.e("next","click");
    }
});
```

My code is working properly but if I uncoment v.performClick(); to remove warning I get unwanted behaviour. Why am I getting this warning and is there going to be some problems if I discard it and leave the code as is?

**EDIT:**

this is my log when I click on button:
*"next", "touch"

"next", "touch"

"next", "click"*

and this is with v.performClick()
*"next", "click"

"next", "touch"

"next", "click"

"next", "touch"*
"next", "click"

Answer (score 9):

You should put the

```
v.performClick();
```

inside the second if:

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ....) {
    v.performClick();
    detect.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: @lenooh Can you explain why you recommend putting the v.performClick() after the second if with ACTION_UP rather than with ACTION_DOWN?

Comment: AJW: it was a long time ago, I can't remember now. Try both versions, and see what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

one more variant is suppress a warning

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
```